# I get an error when I try to fit my dataset to a logarithmic family?

Tags: r, logarithm

I have a dataframe:

```
               Incidence <- data.frame(Inc. = c(0.4400, 0.5102, 0.2979, 0.2667, 0.0000, 0.0000,
                             0.0200, 0.0213, 0.0000, 0.0238, 0.0256, 0.0000,
                             0.0000, 0.1538, 0.0417, 0.0000, 0.0734, 0.0000,
                             0.0000, 0.0000, 0.1293, 0.0072, 0.0000, 0.0078,
                             0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0068, 0.0000, 0.0000,
                             0.0068), 
                    Habitat = c("Crop", "Crop", "Crop", "Crop", "Edge", "Edge", 
                                "Edge", "Edge", "Edge", "Edge", "Edge", "Edge", 
                                "Edge", "Edge", "Edge", "Oakwood", "Oakwood", 
                                "Oakwood", "Oakwood", "Oakwood", "Oakwood", 
                                "Oakwood", "Oakwood", "Wasteland", "Wasteland", 
                                "Wasteland", "Wasteland", "Wasteland", "Wasteland", 
                                "Wasteland", "Wasteland"), 
                    Season = c("Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Autumn", 
                               "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Spring", "Spring", 
                               "Spring", "Spring", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", 
                               "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Spring",
                               "Spring", "Spring", "Spring", "Autumn", "Autumn", 
                               "Autumn", "Autumn", "Spring", "Spring", "Spring", 
                               "Spring"), 
                    Site = c("M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", 
                             "L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L1", "L2", "L3", "Q1", 
                             "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "E1", 
                             "E2", "E3", "E4", "E1", "E2", "E3", "E4"))
```

I've checked the distribution of my data with the package rriskdistribution. These results showed me that my data follow a logarithmic distribution.

I tried to make a generalized mixed lineal model (glmm) using log family:

```
     GlM_habitats = lme4::glmer(Inc. ~ Habitat +(1|Season)+(1|Site), data = Incidence, family = Gamma(link = "inverse"))
```

Obtaining the next output:

```
    Error in model.frame.default(data = Incidence, drop.unused.levels = TRUE,  : invalid type (list) for variable 'Inc.'
```

I've read that this error is produced because there are zero values in my dataset. As you can see above, my dataset has not any zero value. How can I solve this trouble?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I ran the code and got the same error as StephanKolassa. Most likely you need to explain what is the model you are trying to fit. Looking at your question, it seems like the error was solved, would you agree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the one hand, your error tells you that `Incidence` is not of the correct data type. This is not surprising, since `Incidence` is your `data.frame`, and you presumably want to refer to its *column* called `Inc.`. So you need to change your call to

```
GlM_habitats = lme4::glmer(Inc. ~ Habitat +(1|Season)+(1|Site), data = Incidence, family = Gamma(link = "inverse"))
```

This will give you a different error:

```
non-positive values not allowed for the 'Gamma' family
```

This says that zeros are not allowed in the variable you are modeling (`Inc.`) for a gamma link function. The gamma distribution is strictly positive. Zeros cannot be modeled with it.

Looking at your data with "many" zeros and otherwise positive values, I would rather suggest a zero inflation model, or a hurdle one.

Comment: After run that code I got this error: Error in model.frame.default(data = Incidence, drop.unused.levels = TRUE,  :   invalid type (list) for variable 'Inc.'  How can I handle it?

Comment: Are you sure you ran the code I wrote in my answer? Note that I have `Inc.~...`, not `Incidence~...`. As I write, my line of code gives me "non-positive values not allowed for the 'Gamma' family", which I address in my second paragraph.

Comment: Yes, sorry I have a column called Incidence. To avoid any mistake, because the dataframe name is Incidence too,  I used Inc. as column name.

Comment: You need to use the *column name* in the formula, and the name of the `data.frame` for the `data` parameter.

Comment: Please Mr Stephan check my post update. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I just opened a completely new R console and pasted the exact two commands from your answer into the console. I get the "non-positive values not allowed for the 'Gamma' family" error. Have you done this? (Or are you using your original data instead of what is in your post?) Also, what R version are you running (use `sessionInfo()`)`?

Comment: Yes, I have reopen a R console and I've got the same error as you: Error in eval(family$initialize, rho) :  non-positive values not allowed for the 'Gamma' family. When I execute sessionInfo I got this output R version 4.0.2 RC (2020-06-14 r78688).

Comment: Well, that is not "the same error". That is the error I get too, and I address it in the second paragraph. I'll edit my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Dear Mr Stephan how is a model with a zero inflation, or a hurdle one?

Comment: That is a different question. Please take a little time to read up on these models, there is a lot of information on the internet. If you then have any more questions, please feel free to post them here. We also have a [tag:zero-inflation] tag.